# Verified email from LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is the email address returned from your public API guaranteed to be verified? `email-address` accessible via the `r_emailaddress` member permission here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile.

Comment: I think it is better to ask LinkedIn support directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `email-address` from the `r_emailaddress` member permission must be verified (aka confirmed) since (a) this is the primary email address and (b) LinkedIn only allows confirmed email addresses to be registered as a primary email address. Of course, an email address that was confirmed before may fall out of use so there is that scenario.

From LinkedIn's [Basic Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) page:

> email-address: The LinkedIn member's primary email address. Secondary email addresses associated with the member are not available via the API.

From LinkedIn's [How do I update the email addresses for my account?](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/60/~/changing,-adding,-or-removing-your-email-address) page:

> An email address must be confirmed before it can be made your primary email address.

I also just verified this with the following:

1. Creating an Account: An account cannot be created without verifying a primary email address. When attempting to access the API with a partially created account without verifying a primary email address, the following error is returned "A confirmed email address is required to proceed."
2. Changing Primary Email Address in Existing Account: When adding an email address to an existing account, LinkedIn will only allow you to make an email address the primary email address if it is verified. In the "Add & change email addresses" dialog, the "Make primary" link only appears for verified email addresses. A "Send confirmation email" link appears for non-verified email addresses.